# Why is Data.Word in Haskell called that?

Tags: haskell

Why is an unsigned integral type in Haskell called "Word"? Does the "ord" stand for "ordinal"?

Here is the documentation on Data.Word:
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Word.html#t:Word

This is a very hard question to google!

Comment: I'd speculate the reason they didn't call it `Unsigned` (or `UInt`) is to avoid everybody from [starting to refine their `Int` signatures when they want to state some number to always be positive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432154/int-vs-word-in-common-use).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29#Words):

> The term 'word' is used for a small group of bits which are handled simultaneously by processors of a particular architecture. The size of a word is thus CPU-specific. Many different word sizes have been used, including 6-, 8-, 12-, 16-, 18-, 24-, 32-, 36-, 39-, 48-, 60-, and 64-bit. Since it is architectural, the size of a word is usually set by the first CPU in a family, rather than the characteristics of a later compatible CPU. The meanings of terms derived from word, such as longword, doubleword, quadword, and halfword, also vary with the CPU and OS.

In short, a word is a fixed-length group of bits that the CPU can process.  We normally work with words that are powers of two, since modern CPUs handle those very well.  A `word` in particular is not really a number, although we treat it as such for most purposes.  Instead, just think of it as a fixed number of bits in RAM that you can manipulate.  A common use for something like `Word8` is to implement ASCII C-style strings, for example.  Haskell's implementation treats `WordN` types as unsigned integers that implement `Num`, among other type classes.

---

There is a module called `Data.Ord` where "Ord" stands for "Ordering".  It has extra functions for working with comparisons of datatypes and is where the `Ordering` datatype and `Ord` typeclass are defined.  It is unrelated to `Data.Word`.