# Why is unsigned int so rare in haskell?

Tags: haskell

Generally Haskell libraries make a point of making impossible states unrepresentable in the types. But I often see `Int` used where only a non-negative number makes sense. Why is `Word` not used in those cases?

Comment: This question, though very interesting, is likely to have just subjective answers. As such, it does not meet the SO requirements.

Comment: Previously asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432154/int-vs-word-in-common-use

Answer (score 22, accepted):

We only just now got [`Numeric.Natural`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Numeric-Natural.html) in `base`, too.

I think it is just historical accident. `Int` and `Integer` were in the haskell 98 prelude, which didn't get bogged down with lots of other fixed-size integer types.